# Trying to deploy code with capistrano

Tags: capistrano3

Trying to deploy code with capistrano  , but an error appears :

```
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sol : In command line , do

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```